# React conditional rendering useState hook but not triggering

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Been playing with react for a while and came across an issue that I can't explain. In the below code, I am conditionally showing a `div` if the `useState` hook `visibleDialog` is set to true. When I call a change to the state via the context menu item, the value of the state changes but the div is never rendered. I am pretty sure I am following the same pattern that I have used in many other places, but this just does not work. What should I be looking at or trying here to see what I have messed up?

Thank you

```
export const TreeUnselectedAttribute = props => {
    const [visibleDialog, setVisibleDialog] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const MENU_ID = `cm-${props.treeItem.index}`;
    const { show } = useContextMenu({
        id: MENU_ID,
    });

    const handleClickRemove = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        show(e);
    }

    const handleRemoveClick = (e) => {
        props.onRemoveTreeItem(props.treeItem);
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
    }

    const handleClickShowAttributeSelectDialog = (e) => {
        setVisibleDialog(true);
    }

    const hideAttributeSelectDialog = () => {
        setVisibleDialog(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div onContextMenu={handleClickRemove}>
                    <span key="0" /> {props.treeItem.branchXmlNode.name}
                </div>
                <Menu id={MENU_ID} theme={theme.dark}>
                    <Item onClick={handleRemoveClick}>Remove</Item>
                    <Separator />
                    <Submenu label="Add">
                        <Item onClick={handleClickShowAttributeSelectDialog}>Attribute</Item>
                    </Submenu>
                </Menu>
                {(visibleDialog &&
                    <div>Tester</div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

The above component is called via a kendo react treeview that conditionally renders this component based on a node type:

```
const fetchTreeItemView = (props) => {

        let item: TreeViewDataItem = props.item;

        return (
            <>
                {(item.branchType == fetchBranchType.entity) &&
                    <TreeUnselectedEntityNode treeItem={item} />
                }
                {(item.branchType == fetchBranchType.attribute) &&
                    <TreeUnselectedAttribute treeItem={item} onRemoveTreeItem={onRemoveTreeItem} onAddTreeItem={onAddTreeItem} />
                }
                {(!item.selected && item.branchType == fetchBranchType.filter) &&
                    <span key="0" /> && `${item.branchXmlNode.type ?? "and"}`
                }
                {(!item.selected && item.branchType == fetchBranchType.linkentity) &&
                    <span key="0" /> && `${item.branchXmlNode.name} link type: ${item.branchXmlNode.linktype}`
                }
                {(!item.selected && item.branchType == fetchBranchType.condition) &&
                    <span key="0" /> && `${item.condition.attribute} ${item.condition.operator} ${item.condition.value ?? ""}`
                }
                {(!item.selected && (item.branchType == fetchBranchType.root)) &&
                    <span key="0" /> && `${item.text}`
                }
                {(item.selected && item.branchType == fetchBranchType.filter) &&
                    <span key="0" /> && <span><ComboBox
                        style={{ width: "80px" }}
                        data={["and", "or"]}
                        defaultValue={item.text}
                    />
                    </span>
                }
                {(item.selected && item.branchType == fetchBranchType.condition) &&
                    <TreeSelectedCondition treeItem={item} querySettings={querySettings} />
                }
            </>
        );
    };


<TreeView data={processTreeViewItems(tree, {
                            select: select
                        })}
                            expandIcons={true}
                            item={fetchTreeItemView}
                            onExpandChange={onExpandChange}
                            onItemClick={onTreeItemClick} />
```

Comment: I guess the problem is from `Item` component, where is your `Item` declared?

Comment: @NickVu Its inside of a kendo react TreeView where the tree nodes call components based on a node type

Comment: I would suggest temporarily putting `visibleDialog ? <div>Tester</div> : <div>another tester</div>` to check if there is some other problem with rendering the div

Answer (score 0):

the div may cover by other,I suggest you can give the div an style like `postion:'absolute';top:0;left:0` to check the div is really exist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).